# Magento ->getSku() or getData(’sku’) returns empty string

Tags: php, magento

I have Magento 1.3.2 and I have weird issue:

When I am in `list.phtml`, and I try to fetch the SKU by using `getSku()` or `getData('sku')` I get empty string. `getName()` does work. However, when I do that from other pages, it works well.

I `var_dump`-ed it and no SKU is shown.

What can cause this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The other option is to re-load the product object in the list.phtml using the ID of the product you already have.  The code reads something a little like:

```
$sku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSku();
```

Note that $_product is what you are getting in your collection already, and note that getSku is case sensitive (as are all Magento attributes getter/setters).

@Prattski's solution is preferable as you don't really want to be messing with loading/manipulating the objects, but it sounds as though your collection is a little messed up. SKU is one of the core fields that exists in the base `catalog_product_entity` table, so would be unusual not to be loaded.

Comment: Dear future readers, this solution has quite big performance impact if it is used inside foreach loop over collection.

Answer (score 50):

I'm surprised nobody has given you the easiest and most proper answer yet:

Go to your admin, *Catalog >> Attributes >> Manage Attributes*.  Then edit the *'sku'* attribute.  Change the *"Used in Product Listing"* from *'No'* to *'Yes'*.  You will then have access to it from the product object in `list.phtml` with `->getSku()`

Comment: nice idea just i need it in checkout

Comment: Awesome solution, many times the easiest way to do things is overlooked in Magento. Thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution, the accepted solution will cause overloading and perfomance problems

Answer (score 4):

Probably sku is not added to the list of attributes when a collection is retrieved. I assume you are talking a bout the file /template/catalog/product/list.phtml. If so, then you need to extend the corresponding code file (/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php).

I think your best bet is to overload the getLoadedProductCollection() method to:

```
public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        return $this->_getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
    }
```

This might not work, I have not been able to test it, as in my store the sku and all other attributes are accessible in the list.phtml template file.

Comment: It might be a good solution, but I recommend not to extend class but rather use event observer for this (maybe `catalog_block_product_list_collection`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php 
    $current_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    if($current_product) {
        $sku = $current_product->getSku();
        // output sku
        echo $sku;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem too but tried        $_product['sku']
it works for me

Answer (score -3):

$_product["sku"]; enough to get the product sku.